# Captcha is not loading While adding Screen restriction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing my project in MVC. In registration page i am using captcha control. It is working Fine. But my problem is i am adding screen restriction to some of my pages. While adding screen restriction captcha is not getting loaded. 
 can anyone please help me?

I have added the **screen restriction** code below

```
 public class ScreenRestriction : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var routeData = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
            string currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            string currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            string currentArea = routeData.Values["area"] as string;

            var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
            var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            if ((currentAction != "Login" && currentAction != "Create" && currentAction != "GetUser" && currentAction != "Index" ) == true)
            {
                if (session["UserID"] == null)
                {
                    if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        response.StatusCode = 590;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
                        response.Redirect(url.Action("Login", "CU"));
                    }
                    filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

**Screen restriction in Filters**

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new ScreenRestriction());
        }
    }
```

**I have added the registration page code below**

**View--**

```
@model SYTMain.Models.tblUser
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@using CaptchaMvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_for_registration.cshtml";

}
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>tblUser</legend>
 <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressId, "Address1")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tblAddress.Address1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tblAddress.Address1)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressId, "Address2")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tblAddress.Address2)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tblAddress.Address2)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeNumber)
            </div>
   @Html.Captcha(3)
            <br />
            <p class="Error">  @ViewBag.ErrMessage </p>
  <p>

                <a href="Login"> <input type="submit" value="Create" /> </a>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(tblUser tbluser)
        {
            string val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CUTypeId"];
            int code = Convert.ToInt32(val);
            Session["Emailid"] = tbluser.EmailID.Trim();
            if (ModelState.IsValid && this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha Not Valid") )
            {
  EmailManager.SendConfirmationEmailName(tbluser.EmailID, tbluser.FirstName);
 tbluser.UserTypeId = code;
                db.tblUsers.Add(tbluser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { Email = tbluser.EmailID });
            }

            ViewBag.BusinessCategoryId = new SelectList(db.tblBusinessCategories, "BusinessID", "BusinessName", tbluser.BusinessCategoryId);
            ViewBag.UserTypeId = new SelectList(db.tblUserTypes, "UserTypeID", "UserType", tbluser.UserTypeId);
            ViewBag.AddressId = new SelectList(db.tblAddresses, "AddressID", "Address1", tbluser.AddressId);
            ViewBag.ErrMessage = "Error: Captcha not valid";

            return View(tbluser);
        }
```

Comment: Hey @nishra ...have you solved your problem ?